# broken project name showing in project window of netbeans

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans6.8

I have created application in ruby on rails by netbeans 6.8 IDE. But my all application name showing in the project window of netbeans IDE are broken,let say my application name is Test then in the project window it is showing Test(broken). How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a decent editor for working on Rails projects. Try TextMate, Vim or Sublime Text 2.

The problem with IDE's is that they hide a lot of Rails behind menus and buttons. There's also the added problem that your IDE may not (yet) be compatible with the version of Rails you're using.

Don't worry so much about the title of NetBeans, open a real editor and write beautiful code!

Edit: NetBeans probably finds your gems not installed or a failing test or maybe even syntax errors in your project.